# woocommerce plugin does not active

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

when i go to active my woocommerce plugin in my wordpress  it shows this error-

```html
Warning: include_once(/home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 34

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 34

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WooCommerce' not found in /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php(48): WC() #1 /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2255): include('/home/vol6_3/ep...') #2 /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-admin/plugins.php(177): plugin_sandbox_scrape('woocommerce/woo...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epiz_26461129/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 44
```

please help me to activate this plugin in my wordpress account.

Comment: How did you upload the woocommerce package? Via zip and extract or other method?

Comment: I upload woocoomerce plugin directly through wordpress but when i goto active the plugin,it gives me the above error.                                                                                                          By the way, I am using infinityfree web hosting (free vertion).Does the error occurs for this kind of hosting plan?

Comment: You should contact your host. They may be able to assist?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete woocommerce files from server and reinstall it. This May Work